# Unique value issue

Tags: python, django

I've got following model:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180, verbose_name='Nazwa')
    variant = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "variant")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.filter(name=self.name).order_by('-variant')
        try:
            self.variant = vehicles[0].variant+1
        except:
            pass            
        super(Vehicle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is, that when I'm creating new object, that name doesn't occur in database, it creates object with `variant = 1` instead `default 0`. When I'm creating another object with same name, `variant is incremented by 2 instead of 1`.
So, when I'm creating multiple objects with same name, the `variants`go only in odd numbers, `e.g.: 1,3,5,7,9,11...`

What is wrong with my model?

Comment: Because you are doing `vehicles[0].variant+1` __and__ `super(Vehicle, self).save(...`. Save gets called twice so the `variant` is incremented twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in your code: you don't check if this model was saved before. Test case:

```
vehicle = models.Vehicle(name='Foo')
vehicle.save() #variant==0 by default
Vehicle.active = False
vehicle.save() #there is already a record with this name. Increment variant anyway
```

This approach looks better for me:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id is None: #works only when saved first time
        self.variant = Vehicle.objects.filter(name=self.name).count()
    super(Vehicle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```